# create composite primary key using foreign key using hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, primary-key, hibernate-mapping, composite-primary-key

I have a table complaint master which contains a primary key which is further used as a foreign key inside another table named as complaint_treatment having one to many relationship .

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "complaint_master")
    public class ComplaintMaster{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "complaint_id")
        private long complaint_id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy= "complaintMasterForkey", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
        /*@JsonManagedReference(value="ComplaintTreatmentKey-ComplaintMaster")*/
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        private List<ComplaintTreatmentKey> complaintTreatmentKey = new ArrayList<>();

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "submitted_on")
        private Date submitted_on;

        @Column(name = "auth_code")
        private String authCode;

// GETTERS AND SETTERS
    }
```

I have another table complaint_treatment in which i have to create composite primary key but the key two fields that are participating are foreign key.
so i used embeded to solve this issue.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class ComplaintTreatmentKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "ComplaintTreatmentKey-ComplaintMaster")
    @JoinColumn(name = "complaint_id")
    protected ComplaintMaster complaintMasterForkey;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "ComplaintTreatmentKey-ServiceCategory")
    protected ServiceCategory serviceCategoryForKey;
}
```

and then using @EmbeddedId use it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "complaint_treatment")

    public class ComplaintsTreatment {

        @EmbeddedId
        private ComplaintTreatmentKey treatmentComplaintKey;

        @Column(name = "description")
        private String description;

        @JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
        private StatusMaster statusMaster;

        @Column(name = "rca")
        private String rca;

        @JoinColumn(name = "priority_id")
        private PriorityMaster priorityMaster;

        @JoinColumn(name = "assigend_to")
        private Employee assignedTo;

        @Column(name = "closed_on")
        private Date closedOn;
    }
```

but it through an error

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.nxtlife.model.ComplaintMaster.complaintTreatmentKey
```